# Optimize text to ascii lookup map and scalability

Tags: java, optimization, cache, hash-map, lookup

Is there a more optimal way of retrieving the character for the letter? I would assume that I would just replace my Entry set loop with another map, but I do not want to bloat the code, because it will reduce scalability.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class AciiLetters {
    private enum Letter {
        _A("010101111101101"), _B("110101110101110"), _C("011100100100011"),
        _D("110101101101110"), _E("111100110100111"), _F("111100110100100"),
        _G("011100101101011"), _H("101101111101101"), _I("111010010010111"),
        _J("011001001101010"), _K("101101110101101"), _L("100100100100111"),
        _M("101111111101101"), _N("111101101101101"), _O("010101101101010"),
        _P("110101110100100"), _Q("010101101011001"), _R("110101110101101"),
        _S("011100010001110"), _T("111010010010010"), _U("101101101101111"),
        _V("101101101101010"), _W("101101111111101"), _X("101101010101101"),
        _Y("101101010010010"), _Z("111001010100111"), _0("111101101101111"),
        _1("010110010010111"), _2("111001111100111"), _3("111001011001111"),
        _4("101101111001001"), _5("111100111001111"), _6("111100111101111"),
        _7("111001001001001"), _8("111101111101111"), _9("111101111001111"),
        SPACE("000000000000000"), UNKNOWN("010101001010010");

        private static final Map<Character, Letter> cache;
        static {
            cache = new HashMap<Character, Letter>();

            cache.put('A', _A); cache.put('B', _B); cache.put('C', _C);
            cache.put('D', _D); cache.put('E', _E); cache.put('F', _F);
            cache.put('G', _G); cache.put('H', _H); cache.put('I', _I);
            cache.put('J', _J); cache.put('K', _K); cache.put('L', _L);
            cache.put('M', _M); cache.put('N', _N); cache.put('O', _O);
            cache.put('P', _P); cache.put('Q', _Q); cache.put('R', _R);
            cache.put('S', _S); cache.put('T', _T); cache.put('U', _U);
            cache.put('V', _V); cache.put('W', _W); cache.put('X', _X);
            cache.put('Y', _Y); cache.put('Z', _Z); cache.put('0', _0);
            cache.put('1', _1); cache.put('2', _2); cache.put('3', _3);
            cache.put('4', _4); cache.put('5', _5); cache.put('6', _6);
            cache.put('7', _7); cache.put('8', _8); cache.put('9', _9);
            cache.put(' ', SPACE); cache.put('?', UNKNOWN);
        }

        public static final int WIDTH = 3, HEIGHT = 5;
        private String bitSequence;

        Letter(String bitSequence) {
            this.bitSequence = bitSequence;
        }

        public static Letter getEnum(Character value) {
            Letter letter = cache.get(value);

            if (letter != null)
                return letter;

            return UNKNOWN;
        }

        public char getChar() {
            for (Entry<Character, Letter> entry : cache.entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getValue() == this)
                    return entry.getKey();
            }

            return '?';
        }
    }

    public AciiLetters() {
        printText("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 0123456789 ?", "  ");
    }

    public void printText(String text, String spacing) {
        Letter letter;
        int offset;
        String seq;
        Character val;

        for (int row = 0; row < Letter.HEIGHT; row++) {
            for (Character tCh : text.toCharArray()) {
                letter = Letter.getEnum(tCh);
                offset = row * Letter.WIDTH;
                seq = letter.bitSequence.substring(offset, offset + Letter.WIDTH);
                val = letter.getChar();
                for (Character ch : seq.toCharArray()) {
                    System.out.printf("%c", ch == '0' ? ' ' : val);
                }
                System.out.print(spacing);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AciiLetters();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 A   BB    CC  DD   EEE  FFF   GG  H H  III   JJ  K K  L    M M  NNN   O   PP    Q   RR    SS  TTT  U U  V V  W W  X X  Y Y  ZZZ       000   1   222  333  4 4  555  666  777  888  999        ?   
A A  B B  C    D D  E    F    G    H H   I     J  K K  L    MMM  N N  O O  P P  Q Q  R R  S     T   U U  V V  W W  X X  Y Y    Z       0 0  11     2    3  4 4  5    6      7  8 8  9 9       ? ?  
AAA  BB   C    D D  EE   FF   G G  HHH   I     J  KK   L    MMM  N N  O O  PP   Q Q  RR    S    T   U U  V V  WWW   X    Y    Z        0 0   1   222   33  444  555  666    7  888  999         ?  
A A  B B  C    D D  E    F    G G  H H   I   J J  K K  L    M M  N N  O O  P     QQ  R R    S   T   U U  V V  WWW  X X   Y   Z         0 0   1   2      3    4    5  6 6    7  8 8    9        ?   
A A  BB    CC  DD   EEE  F     GG  H H  III   J   K K  LLL  M M  N N   O   P      Q  R R  SS    T   UUU   V   W W  X X   Y   ZZZ       000  111  222  333    4  555  666    7  888  999        ?
```

Comment: BTW: I see nothing that is [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii) specific here.  Your solution appears to be character set agnostic - which is good.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those occasions where a 'sparse' dataset may be very helpful.

But, first some nit-picks:

- You should probably call the class `AsciiLetters` instead of `AciiLetters`
- Declaring multiple constants on one line is unconventinal, and makes things hard to read... fix:

  ```
  public static final int WIDTH = 3, HEIGHT = 5;
  ```
- In the printText you over-cook the lookups to the Enum:

  ```
  for (int row = 0; row < Letter.HEIGHT; row++) {
      for (Character tCh : text.toCharArray()) {
          letter = Letter.getEnum(tCh);
  ```

  this can become:

  ```
  char[] textchars = text.toCharArray();
  Letter[] letters = new Letter[textchars.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < textchars.length; i++) {
      letters[i] = Letter.getEnum(textchars[i]);
  }
  for (int row = 0; row < Letter.HEIGHT; row++) {
      for (letter letter : letters) {
  ```
- also in the printText(), there is no need to do all the work with `Character`. Using `char` is better.
- also, declaring all your variables outside the loop is not useful for anything, and can even make performance worse. Languages like `C` need that, but Java is better if you declare your variables when you need them, not before.
- If you wanted to, you could store the `0` and `1` values as actual bits. This would actually be faster (slightly) but would also be more complicated. In this case, I don't think it is significantly different.

OK, now for the real issue, the storage of the Enums in a convenient-to-access system...

First, I recommend that you change your Enum to have two parameters in the constructor:

```
    private String bitSequence;
    Letter(String bitSequence) {
        this.bitSequence = bitSequence;
    }
```

This should become (note, I have also made them final!):

```
    private final String bitSequence;
    private final char mychar;
    Letter(char c, String bitSequence) {
        this.mychar = c;
        this.bitSequence = bitSequence;
    }
```

Then change each of your Enum values to also send the char it represents.

If you do that, then your getChar() method becomes simply:

```
    public char getChar() {
        return mychar;
    }
```

**BUT**, I was lazy, and I pulled your code in to my eclipse environment, and I could not be bothered to change all the Enum values... so I cheated... and used:

```
    public char getChar() {
        return name().charAt(1);
    }
```

That takes the second letter from the Enum name (e.g. it will pull `L` from `_L`). Since all your Enum names have a systematic name scheme, this will work, but, it's not the best system...

But still, once I have the `getChar()` working off the internal values of the enum (instead of the `Map<...>`), you can do the following:

replace the line:

```
private static final Map<Character, Letter> cache;
```

and instead have:

```
// store enough values for ASCII characters. If we wanted to, even 32768 is not large
// and with that we could store **all** Letters,
private static final Letter[] cache = new Letter[128];
```

Then, in your static block, fill the cache with 'Unknown', and then 'fix' the ones you know:

```
    static {
        // assume things are UNKNOWN.
        Arrays.fill(cache, UNKNOWN);
        // 'fix' the things we actually know...
        for (Letter letter : values()) {
            // use the actual char (cast implicitly to an int...)
            // as the index to the array.
            // if you have chars >= 128 you will need to make the array bigger.
            cache[letter.getChar()] = letter;
        }
    }
```

Finally, using this array is really simple:

```
    public static Letter getEnum(char value) {
        return value < cache.length ? cache[value] : UNKNOWN;
    }
```

Note, I have changed the parameter to simple `char` instead of `Character`.

Putting it all together, I have your code running as (without the additional char as a constructor to the Enum...):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class AsciiLetters {
    private enum Letter {
        _A("010101111101101"), _B("110101110101110"), _C("011100100100011"),
        _D("110101101101110"), _E("111100110100111"), _F("111100110100100"),
        _G("011100101101011"), _H("101101111101101"), _I("111010010010111"),
        _J("011001001101010"), _K("101101110101101"), _L("100100100100111"),
        _M("101111111101101"), _N("111101101101101"), _O("010101101101010"),
        _P("110101110100100"), _Q("010101101011001"), _R("110101110101101"),
        _S("011100010001110"), _T("111010010010010"), _U("101101101101111"),
        _V("101101101101010"), _W("101101111111101"), _X("101101010101101"),
        _Y("101101010010010"), _Z("111001010100111"), _0("111101101101111"),
        _1("010110010010111"), _2("111001111100111"), _3("111001011001111"),
        _4("101101111001001"), _5("111100111001111"), _6("111100111101111"),
        _7("111001001001001"), _8("111101111101111"), _9("111101111001111"),
        SPACE("000000000000000"), UNKNOWN("010101001010010");

        public static final int WIDTH = 3;
        public static final int HEIGHT = 5;

        private static final Letter[] cache = new Letter[128];

        static {
            Arrays.fill(cache, UNKNOWN);
            for (Letter letter : values()) {
                cache[letter.getChar()] = letter;
            }
        }

        private String bitSequence;

        Letter(String bitSequence) {
            this.bitSequence = bitSequence;
        }

        public static Letter getEnum(char value) {
            return value < cache.length ? cache[value] : UNKNOWN;
        }

        public char getChar() {
            return name().charAt(1);
        }
    }

    public AciiLetters() {
        printText("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 0123456789 ?", "  ");
    }

    public void printText(String text, String spacing) {

        char[] textchars = text.toCharArray();
        Letter[] letters = new Letter[textchars.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < textchars.length; i++) {
            letters[i] = Letter.getEnum(textchars[i]);
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < Letter.HEIGHT; row++) {
            for (Letter letter : letters) {
                int offset = row * Letter.WIDTH;
                String seq = letter.bitSequence.substring(offset, offset + Letter.WIDTH);
                char val = letter.getChar();
                for (Character ch : seq.toCharArray()) {
                    System.out.printf("%c", ch == '0' ? ' ' : val);
                }
                System.out.print(spacing);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AciiLetters();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very thorough. I will have to check this in the morning. Note: I didn't realize I spelled ASCII wrong... That was dumb on my part. I may not even have to store the char for each sequence, because I could just get the current letter that was read in from the inputText...

Comment: `return name().charAt(1);` now this is lazy wait for it genius.